# Is there any game analogous to counter strike?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I am very much interested in games. Is there any game analogous to counter strike for ubuntu? If yes how to get it?

Answer (score 5):

These are a few:

- [Urban Terror](http://www.urbanterror.info/home/)
- [America's Army](http://www.americasarmy.com/)
- [True Combat Elite](http://www.truecombatelite.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Counter Strike runs well under [wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3731). So basically you can run it under [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine). Other than that you can install some major games in ubuntu through [PlayDeb](http://www.playdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/11.04/?category=FPS).

P.S. Pardon me for genre selection on the link, I am not much of a gamer myself :)